# Ember Data with Websockets

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In the ember guides on models it says ([1](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/)) :

> Ember Data is also designed to work with streaming APIs like socket.io, Firebase, or WebSockets. You can open a socket to your server and push changes to records into the store whenever they occur.

I tried writing a custom adapter that uses a websocket but i'm not getting very far. I couldn't find any working examples anywhere.

This is my totally unfinished prototype:

```
DS.WSAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend(Ember.Evented, {

    websocket: undefined,

    init: function () {
        if(this.websocket === undefined)
        {
            this.websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8887');

            this.websocket.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");

            };
            this.websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
                // What to do here?
            }; 
        }

        this._loadData();
    },

    //....
```

Can somone please help me with the websocket adapter?

My main problem is that I have no clue what to do when the `websocket.onmessage()` gets executed. I can't even access the store (using `DS.get('defaultStore')`) or anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience working directly with sockets in Ember, however I have recently completed an Ember Data + Firebase adapter which should follow very similar methodologies.

You should, at the least, be able to use it as inspiration:

https://github.com/sandersonet/ember-data-firebase

Firebase does provide an additional layer of abstraction from the sockets underneath, but the methodologies are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/#toc_how-do-i-inform-ember-data-about-new-records-created-on-the-backend

> Some applications may want to add or update records in the store
>   without requesting the record via store.find. To accomplish this you
>   can use the DS.Store's push, pushPayload, or update methods. This is
>   useful for web applications that have a channel (such as SSE or Web
>   Sockets) to notify it of new or updated records on the backend.

Basically, you need to deserialize data you receive in your `onmessage` hook and push new objects to the data store using `store.push('model', record)` or alternative methods.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken (redirects to 404). Perhaps this is a good replacement link? 
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/